# can't find referenced method boolean isInstantApp() in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, apk

I am getting two error while generating signed apk in android studio 3.
when i try to build it build successfully.
Please help how to resolve this error.

but when i try generate signed apk i get following errors.

Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbga: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp()' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager

Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgb: can't find referenced method 'boolean isInstantApp(java.lang.String)' in library class android.content.pm.PackageManager

following is my build.gradle file code.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.micropeda.sudoku"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 20171216
        versionName "2.4.1"
    }


  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved my self, i just update build.gradle file.
Here is my updated build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.micropeda.sudoku"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 20171216
        versionName "2.4.1"
    }


 buildTypes {
      release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'
}
```